# How to use std::fill on an template type array made using make_unique<T[]>()?

Tags: c++, c++14

I want to create class for my 2d matrix. I have used the following code

```
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
private:
  int row{};
  int col{};
  std::unique_ptr<T[]> data; // We are going to store data into a 1d array

public:
  explicit Matrix(int row, int col, T def) {
    // Creates a T type matrix of row rows and col columns
    // and initialize each element by def
    this->row = row;
    this->col = col;
    this->data = std::make_unique<T[]>(row*col);
    for(int i=0; i<row*col; i++) {
      data[i] = def;
    }
  }

  void setValues(T value) {
    // Set the value in all the elements
    for (int i=0; i<row*col; i++) {
      data[i] = value;
    }
  }
};
```

Now I want to replace the loops with `std::fill` but somehow I am not able to do this. All the examples are on `std::vector<T>` or on `std::array<T>`. Can anyone help me with this please?

**EDIT 1:** One way as @StoryTeller - Unslander Monica mentioned is

```
std::fill(&data[0], &data[0] + row*col , def);
```

Is there any cleaner way?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/713479/2912665

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::fill` expects a pair of iterators (that could be pointers) which define a valid range. In your case the range is from the address of the first element `&data[0]`, up to one past the end `&data[0] + row*col`. Translating it into an invocation, we get

```
std::fill(&data[0], &data[0] + row*col , def);
```

or the equivalent, but in my opinion not quite as obvious:

```
std::fill(data.get(), data.get() + row*col , def);
```

Another approach, is to let the standard library do the arithmetic itself, and use the complementary algorithm `std::fill_n`. Thus producing one of these options.

```
std::fill_n(&data[0], row*col , def);
std::fill_n(data.get(), row*col , def);
```

Comment: Thanks..I was doing `std::fill(data, data+(row*col), def)` which was definitely not working.

Comment: @MayukhSarkar yout need to use `data.get()` to get the actual pointer.

Comment: You can also use fill_n().

Comment: @MichaëlRoy - True. I guess I was tunnel visioned by the OP's mention of `std::fill`. Why not post an answer?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thanks..`fill_n` looks cleaner though