# C++ vector literals, or something like them

Tags: c++, vector, literals

I'm writing some code against a C++ API that takes vectors of vectors of vectors, and it's getting tedious to write code like the following all over the place:

```
vector<string> vs1;
vs1.push_back("x");
vs1.push_back("y");
...
vector<string> vs2;
...
vector<vector<string> > vvs1;
vvs1.push_back(vs1);
vvs1.push_back(vs2);
...
vector<vector<string> > vvs2;
...
vector<vector<vector<string> > > vvvs;
vvvs.push_back(vvs1);
vvvs.push_back(vvs2);
...
```

Does C++ have a vector literal syntax? I.e., something like:

```
vector<vector<vector<string>>> vvvs = 
    { { {"x","y", ... }, ... }, ... }
```

Is there a non-builtin way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In [C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x) you [will be able](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Initializer_lists) to use your desired syntax:

```
vector<vector<vector<string> > > vvvs = 
    { { {"x","y", ... }, ... }, ... };
```

But in today's C++ you are limited to using [boost.assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html) which lets you do:

```
vector<string> vs1;
vs1 += "x", "y", ...;
vector<string> vs2;
...
vector<vector<string> > vvs1;
vvs1 += vs1, vs2, ...;
vector<vector<string> > vvs2;
...
vector<vector<vector<string> > > vvvs;
vvvs += vvs1, vvs2, ...;
```

... or using [Qt's containers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html) which let you do it in one go:

```
QVector<QVector<QVector<string> > > vvvs =
    QVector<QVector<QVector<string> > >() << (
        QVector<QVector<string> >() << (
            QVector<string>() << "x", "y", ...) <<
            ... ) <<
        ...
    ;
```

The other semi-sane option, at least for flat vectors, is to construct from an array:

```
string a[] = { "x", "y", "z" };
vector<string> vec(a, a + 3);
```

Comment: I would recommend using an automated way of retrieving the array size, as the one posted by litb here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437150/can-someone-explain-this-template-code-that-gives-me-the-size-of-an-array

Comment: Yep sure. Didnt wanna complicate the answer.

Comment: C++0x is now a thing, and has been renamed c++11

Answer (score 3):

Basically, there's no built-in syntax to do it, because C++ doesn't know about vectors ether; they're just from a convenient library.

That said, if you're loading up a complicated data structure, you should load it from a file or something similar anyway; the code is too brittle otherwise.

Comment: not only should such a structure not be hardcoded, but I think the fact that such nested vectors are being manipulated directly is a code smell... there should probably be a class encapsulating some or all of that.

Comment: STL is not just a _convenient_ library, it's a **standard** library.  C++ is built in layers, but that doesn't mean that the pieces were built in a vacuum.

Comment: You're right, I don't find STL all that convenient a library.

Comment: @CharlieMartin Pre-C++11, I would agree. Nowadays? Not at all.

Comment: Observe the date on the question.