# Random string from array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, random

I cannot define a string array for unknown reasons on C++. I need to randomly get a string from this array.

Been trying the following:

`string bands[] = { "Rammstein", "Slipknot", "Franz Ferdinand", "Gorillaz" };`

I'm getting the following as error:

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'bands'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C3845: 'SpurdoSparde::Form1::bands': only static data members can be initialized inside a ref class or value type
```

Just a reminder, I'm using a Windows forms applications. Not sure if it makes any difference whatsoever.

Comment: Did you forget `std::` or to include `<string>`?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: You should use an `std::vector` instead of a `[]` array.

Comment: Make sure you have `#include <string>` and prefix `string` with `std::` as in `std::string bands[]] = {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are not including `string` and/or not `using std::string`. The following works:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string bands[] = { "Rammstein", "Slipknot", "Franz Ferdinand", "Gorillaz" };
}
```

If you are after a dynamically sized collection of strings, you should prefer `std::vector<std::string>` over a C-style array. If you need fixed size, have a look at `std::array<std::string, N>` or `tr1` or `boost` alternatives if you don't have C++11.

Comment: I did include it from the beginning, and then again, I'm using a forms application rather than a command line, so the `int main()` does not apply, I suppose.

Comment: @P1CUnrelated `main()` is irrelevant here, it could have been any function.

Answer (score 1):

You either didn't include `#include <string>` or need to add the `std::` namespace qualifier to your type:

```
std::string bands[] = { ... };
```

Prefer this over doing `using namespace std;`.

Also, you <s>might</s> should prefer to use a `std::vector` rather than a plain old C-style array:

```
std::vector<std::string> bands = { ... };
```

Comment: As of your example, I got the following: `error C2039: 'vector' : is not a member of 'std'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body` Sorry about the formatting, it's really weird for me.

Comment: vector literal is not quite like that (yet): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758118/c-vector-literals-or-something-like-them

Comment: @P1CUnrelated you need `#include <vector>`. Go to http://en.cppreference.com and search for "vector".

Comment: My bad, I fixed that before posting, but regardless, `'HorseRacing::Form1::bands': only static data members can be initialized inside a ref class or value type`, and `cannot define 'bands' as a member of managed 'HorseRacing::Form1': mixed types are not supported`. It's really weird, I have done this before.

Comment: It's perfectly fine in C++11. It uses `std::vector::vector(std::initializer_list<T> init, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );`.

Comment: @thang well, if you replace the `...` by `"hello", "world"` then it should work. I see no reason it wouldn't work in C++11.

Comment: @juanchopanza, that's c++0x isn't it?  try changing to c++: http://ideone.com/lr4zaB

Comment: I suspect this is actually the issue that OP is having with his compile error.

Comment: @thang C++0x is just what C++11 was called when they expected it to be standardized before 2010. C++ on ideone is C++03.

Comment: @sfrabbit, you're right.  forgot it went through.  although i think op is using visual studio (or borland?), so he's seeing the same error...

Comment: @thang it is C++11, which is now C++. The `vector` initialization shown is completely correct according to the current standard. So, it works in C++, it does not work in C++03.