# Making unnamed container in c++ for temporary comparison in unit test

Tags: c++, python, unit-testing, containers

In unit test code in C++, when I need to compare two vectors, I create temporary vector to store expected values.

```
std::vector<int> expected({5,2,3, 15});
EXPECT_TRUE(Util::sameTwoVectors(result, expected));
```

Can I make it one line? In python, I can generate a list with "[...]".

```
sameTwoVectors(members, [5,2,3,15])
```

Comment: You're looking for a vector literal. Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758118/c-vector-literals-or-something-like-them) answer help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) includes an [initializer-list constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) that takes a [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) you can use the uniform initialization syntax as long as the `sameTwoVectors` function accepts a vector by value, rvalue reference or `const` reference.

```
namespace Util
{
    bool sameTwoVectors(
        const std::vector<int>& result,
        const std::vector<int>& expected)
        {
            return result == expected;
        }
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> result;

    EXPECT_TRUE(Util::sameTwoVectors(result, {5,2,3,15}));
}
```

Optionally, if `sameTwoVectors` only does a simple comparison you can eliminate it. Just use a comparison expression in its place when you call `EXPECT_TRUE`. The trade-off is that you have to specify `std::vector<int>` explicitly instead of relying on the implicit conversion constructor. It's a couple of characters less and a bit clearer what the expected result is.

```
EXPECT_TRUE(result == std::vector<int>({5,2,3,15}));
```

Comment: It's worth noting that there's a specific term for that. It has an initializer-list constructor. See N3485 § 8.5.4/2.

Answer (score 1):

If `Util::sameTwoVectors` expects const reference or just a value you can (assuming [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) support) write it like that

```
EXPECT_TRUE(Util::sameTwoVectors(result, std::vector<int>{5, 2, 3, 15}));
```