# Typedeffing a function (NOT a function pointer)

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers, typedef

```
typedef void int_void(int);
```

`int_void` is a function taking an integer and returning nothing.

My question is: **can it be used "alone", without a pointer?** That is, is it possible to use it as simply `int_void` and not `int_void*`?

```
typedef void int_void(int);
int_void test;
```

This code compiles. But can `test` be somehow used or assigned to something (without a cast)?

---

```
/* Even this does not work (error: assignment of function) */
typedef void int_void(int);
int_void test, test2;
test = test2;
```

Comment: Have you tried actually compiling something like this? If so, what were the results? What was the actual source code?

Comment: Like I said in the question, it compiles. The actual source code is this. Just wrap it in `int main()`.

Comment: Notice that there is a restriction of what can be done with such a type. You are not allowed to use a dependent type for a function declaration that doesn't use the function declarator syntax: `template<typename T> struct f { T g; } ... f<void()> s;` this is ill-formed rather than declaring a member function of type `void()`, because `T` is a dependent function type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happens is that you get a shorter declaration for functions.

You can call `test`, but you will need an actual `test()` function.

You cannot assign anything to test because it is a label, essentially a constant value.

You can also use `int_void` to define a function pointer as Neil shows.

---

### Example

```
typedef void int_void(int);

int main()
{
    int_void test; /* Forward declaration of test, equivalent to:
                    * void test(int); */
    test(5);
}

void test(int abc)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a really cool way to confuse people! I added the testcase I wrote to make sure what you said actually worked, I hope you don't mind

Comment: No, thank you. Alas, I can't figure a way to use it for the function itself, though. It would be cool to be able to eg. `pthread_entryfn a {`

Comment: It should be pointed out that the typedef can be used to declare a function, but it cannot be used to define the function, which is why in the example above the declaration of `test` and the definition look nothing alike. As far as I know, all other typedef'ed names can be used for both declaration and definition.

Comment: @Andreas, not only it can confuse people, but also GCC: try `struct foo { void f(); }; typedef void ftype(); struct bar { friend ftype foo::f; };` and see GCC failing.

Comment: @Johannes: +1 even though if we had a +1 for every gcc bug we'd all be moderator gods.. ;-)

Comment: In particular, you can use it for a function template: `template<typename T> int_void test;`

Answer (score 3):

You are not declaring a variable; you are making a forward declaration of a function.

```
typedef void int_void(int);
int_void test;
```

is equivalent to

```
void test(int);
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be used in the following cases (out of the top of my head):

- generic code:

  boost::function<int_void> func;
- other typedefs:

  typedef int_void* int_void_ptr;
- declarations:

  void add_callback(int_void* callback);

There may be others.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's legal - the following demonstrates its use:

```
typedef void f(int);

void t( int a ) {
}

int main() {
    f * p = t;
    p(1); // call t(1)
}
```

and actually, this C++ code compiles (with g++) & runs - I'm really not sure how kosher it is though.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void f(int);

void t( int a ) {
    printf( "val is %d\n", a );
}

int main() {
    f & p = t;   // note reference not pointer
    p(1);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that you can use it as a pointer, but I specifically asked if it can be used without one :P (And, if not, why I can define a variable of that type) `My question is: can it be used "alone", without a pointer?  That is, is it possible to use it as simply int_void and not int_void*?`

Comment: @Andreas No. What would it mean?

Comment: It is definitely kosher. Shorter form of `void(&p)() = t;`

Comment: @Johannes But how come I can initialise a reference with a pointer?

Comment: @Neil, it's not a pointer but it's a function. The function-to-pointer conversion is done only when needed, like with arrays. As written, `t` is an lvalue and has type `void(int)`.

Comment: @Neil, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516958/could-someone-please-explain-the-difference-between-a-reference-and-a-pointer/1517195#1517195

Comment: @Johannes  Thanks. Always good to learn something new - I don't think I've ever seen a function reference before, or maybe I just didn't notice them.

Comment: Another question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480248/function-references

Answer (score 0):

Pointers to functions are values in C/C++. Functions are not.

Answer (score -1):

This should work, no casting required:

```
void f(int x) { printf("%d\n", x); }

int main(int argc, const char ** argv)
{
    typedef void (*int_void)(int);
    int_void test = f;
    ...
 }
```

A function's name "devolves" into a function pointer anytime you use the function's name in something other than a function call.  If is is being assigned to a func ptr of the same type, you don't need a cast.

The original

```
typedef int_void(int);
```

is not useful by itself, without using a pointer to the type.  So the answer to your question is "no, you can't use that typedef without a pointer".