# What is the best way to create a sub array from an exisiting array in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, arrays

OK, I am trying to get a sub array from an existing array and I'm just not sure how to do it. In my example I have a very large array, but I want to create an array from the last 5 elements of the array.

An example of what I am talking about would be:

```
int array1 = {1,2,3,...99,100};
int array2[5] = array1+95;
```

I know this isn't correct, but I am having some trouble getting it right. I want to get the elements 96 through 100 in array1 and put them into array2 but I don't want to copy the arrays. I just want array2 to start at the 96 element such that array1[96] and array2[0] would be pointing to the same location.

Comment: Keep in mind you won't technically be making a sub-array by pointing to an element.

Comment: The 96th element of `array1` is `array1[95]`.  When you say "put them in array2", it *means* copying, how else will you put them in array2?  There is no way to do what you want.  You need to either copy the elements, or have a pointer that points to the 96th element of `array1`, or have an array of 5 pointers, and have the pointer `i` point to the element `95+i` of `array1`.

Comment: you are correct, by "putting them array2" I didn't mean to copy. I am sorry for the mix-up in terminology.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

for this:

```
"such that array1[96] and array2[0] would be pointing to the same location."
```

you can do:

```
int *arr2 = arr1 + 96;
assert(arr2[0] == arr1[96] == 97);
```

Comment: That `assert` should be a mathematician asserting, not C :-)

Answer (score 8):

A reference hack from a C programmer willing to subvert the type system to get what works:

```
int (&array2)[5] = (int (&)[5])(*(array1 + 5));
```

Now `array2` will be an array for all intents and purposes, and will be a sub-array of `array1`, and will even be passable to that famous C++ `array_size` template function. Though the best way to handle this hackery is to hide it with more hackery!

```
#define make_sub_array(type, arr, off, len) (type (&)[len])(*(arr + off));

int (&array2)[5] = make_sub_array(int, array1, 5, 5);
```

Nice. Terrible by some standards, but the end result a) looks pretty neat, b) does exactly what you want, c) is functionally identical to an actual array, and d) will also have the added bonus (or mis-feature) of being an identical reference to the original, so the two change together.

UPDATE: If you prefer, a templated version (sort of):

```
template <typename T, size_t M>
T (&_make_sub_array(T (&orig)[M], size_t o))[]
{
    return (T (&)[])(*(orig + o));
}
#define make_sub_array(type, array, n, o) (type (&)[n])_make_sub_array(array, o)

int (&array2)[5] = make_sub_array(int, array1, 5, 5);
```

We still have to pass the type. Since one of our arguments must be used as part the cast, we cannot cleanly (IMHO) avoid the macro. We could do this:

```
template <typename T, size_t M, size_t N>
T (&make_sub_array(T (&orig)[M], size_t o))[N]
{
    return (T (&)[N])(*(orig + o));
}

int (&array2)[5] = make_sub_array<int, 15, 5>(array1, 5);
```

But the goal here is to make the calling code as clean as possible, and that call is a bit hairy. The pure-macro version probably has the least overhead and is probably the cleanest to implement in this case.

Comment: Thanks. It took me much longer because I wanted to make it work with actual C++ casting, but eventually I gave up and made it _work_. Improvements (especially a potential version of `make_sub_array` as a template function - I tried that for a while as well before giving up) welcome.

Comment: @Chris: My C++-fu isn't great, I am more of a C person, but I will try!

Comment: That's slick... er ugly... I mean, I'm impressed.  The macro helps readability, but the declaration of array2 is still sort of weird. +1 for the fu

Comment: I could make the macro `#define make_sub_array(type, orig, new, off, len) type (&new)[len] = (type (&)[len])(*(orig + off))` so that it's called as a single statement: `make_sub_array(int, array1, array2, 5, 5);` but I would (personally) prefer to see the assignment in my code so that it's clear that we're declaring and defining a variable.

Comment: `template <typename T, size_t N> size_t array_size(T (&arr)[N]) { return N; }` is the template function `array_size` that returns the size of an array, regardless of type (or size). It doesn't find the size of the array per-se. It takes a reference to an array of a set size. The template just allows that size to vary. We end up not really needing the array itself for anything other than determining the template arguments. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437150/can-someone-explain-this-template-code-that-gives-me-the-size-of-an-array

Answer (score 4):

You can use [boost::iterator_range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/range/index.html) to represent "slices" of arrays/containers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/range.hpp>

int main()
{
    int array[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    // Create a "proxy" of array[5..7]
    // The range implements the concept of a random sequence containter
    boost::iterator_range<int*> subarray(&array[5], &array[7]+1);

    // Output: 3 elements: 5 6 7
    std::cout << subarray.size() << " elements: "
              << subarray[0] << " "
              << subarray[1] << " "
              << subarray[2] << "\n";
}
```

Note that the iterator range "knows" about the size of the sub-array. It will even do bounds checking for you. You cannot get that functionality from a simple pointer.

The usefulness of Boost.Range will become more apparent once you learn about STL containers and iterators.

If you're into linear algebra, [Boost.uBlas](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) supports ranges and slices for its matrices and vectors.

Answer (score 3):

For a completely different approach you could do something like.

```
vector<int> v0(array1 + 95, array1 + 100);
```

or

```
vector<int> v1(array1, array1 + 100);
vector<int> v2(v1.begin() + 95, v1.end());
```

This would make a real copy of the elements of your vector.

Comment: Should be `std::vector` for pendantry. Anyway, +1 for the most "C++" answer.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can use an int pointer as an int array, so getting the array2 to start at item 96 in array1 is easy, but there isn't any way to give array2 a size limit, so you can do this

<strike>int array2[] = &array1[96];</strike>

or this

```
int *array2 = &array1[96];
```

but NOT this

```
int array2[5] = &array1[96]; // this doesn't work.
```

On the other hand, C++ doesn't enforce array size limits anyway, so the only real loss is that you can't use sizeof to get the number of elements in array2.

note:  `&array1[96]` is the same thing as `array+96`

edit: correction - `int array[] = &array[96]` isn't valid, you can only use [] as a synonym for * when declaring a function parameter list.

so this is allowed

```
extern int foo(int array2[]);
foo (&array1[96]);
```

Comment: I still get an error when I try to type in : int array2[] = &array1[96]. The error that I receive is :  cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int []'

Comment: @John: `int array2[] = &array1[96];` is bad.

Comment: Yeah, `int foo[]` and `int *foo` are interchangeable only as function parameters.

Comment: @james: They aren't really interchangeable. Rather, arrays can *decay* into pointers, but they aren't the same.

Comment: @GMan: They are interchangeable as function *parameters* (not *arguments*).  That's unrelated to the decay thing.

Answer (score 0):

You said you don't want to copy the array, but get a pointer to the last five elements.  You almost had it:

```
int array1[] = {1,2,3,...99,100};
int* array2  = &array1[95];
```

Comment: when I tried that I got this error:
cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int []'

Comment: `int array2[] = array1+95;` is illegal.

Comment: Should be

    int array1[] = {1,2,3,...99,100};
    int* array2 = array1+95;

You cannot initialize an array (square brackets) with a pointer -- it can tell where it starts but not its size.

Answer (score 0):

```
int array1[] = {1,2,3,...99,100};
int *array2 = &array1[96];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int arr1[2];
copy(arr + 3, arr + 5, arr1);
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    cout << arr1[i] << endl;
```

The code is not safe if the boundaries are not handled properly.