# Why can't I assign an array to subset of another array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, clang

I want to write a function that returns a part of another array. Here's how I tried to implement it:

```
char *subarrayWithRange(char *array, int location, int length)
{
  char subarray[length];
  subarray = (array + location);
  return subarray;
}
```

When I try to compile it, `clang` gives me this error:

```
error: array type 'char [length]' is not assignable
```

Apparently, I can't assign an array to a sub-array of another array. But, this works when I define the subarray as a pointer:

```
char *subarrayWithRange(char *array, int location, int length)
{
  char *subarray;
  subarray = (array + location);
  return subarray;
}
```

Now, though, I can't define the length of the subarray. Is this a C language thing? Can I get around this somehow?

Comment: You must initialize the array. Or assign to its individual elements.

Comment: look at this question 

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137361/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-sub-array-from-an-exisiting-array-in-c)

Comment: Variable length arrays have been part of C since C99, that's not the problem.

Comment: You could define your own Array struct and then return that. For example in APR you make an array with something like this:
`apr_array_header_t *arr = apr_array_make(pool, 0, sizeof(const char *));`
Do it a similar way for your own struct.

Comment: I think they are allocated on the stack (like when you use `alloca`) and thus cannot be returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign to arrays. You also can't return a local array, since the memory it uses goes out of scope when the function exits. You must use dynamic (heap) memory, using e.g. `malloc()` to allocate.

Also, you must terminate the sub-array if you intend it to be a valid string:

```
char * substringWithRange(const char *string, size_t start, size_t length)
{
  char *p = malloc(length + 1);
  if(p != NULL)
  {
    memcpy(p, string + start, length);
    p[length] = '\0';
  }
  return p;
}
```

Note that the above assumes that the `length` never exceeds the input length, since that is not being checked. You should probably add such checkings, and just truncate.