# How to detect a pointer using by sizeof?

Tags: c

I want to replace the `sprintf()` to `snprintf()` of my project.
So I write a shell to replace `sprintf()` to `MY_SPRINTF`
and then,

```
#define MY_SPRINTF(buf,args...)  snprintf(buf,sizeof(buf), ## args).
```

However, the parameter "buf" is a pointer somewhere in my project that make my replacement not work correctly.

I want to figure out whether the parameter "buf" is a pointer when compiling.
Is it possible ?

Comment: If you can figure out the pointer cases, how are going to handle it? Just use snprintf for arrays and leave the pointer ones with sprintf?

Comment: I will use snprintf for arrays as well as pointer. However, I will check the pointer manually and detect the second parameter for snprintf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to figure out whether the parameter "buf" is a pointer when compiling. Is it possible ?

Arrays and pointers can be distinguished during compile time, see the answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452971/array-size-macro-that-rejects-pointers).  After you replaced `sprintf` by a `MY_SPRINTF` rejecting pointers the compiler halts when `sprintf` is used with a pointer so you need not to check every replacement manually.

```
#define ARRAY_SNPRINTF(buf,...)  \
    snprintf(buf,_Generic(&buf, char (*)[]:sizeof(buf),default:(void)0), __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: Thanks a  lot. I would like to use [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452971/array-size-macro-that-rejects-pointers) to do that.

Comment: @Litchi: added an example macro (C11) to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it, you should not do it, just search for every occurrance of it and fix it accordingly.

If `buf` is an array it will work with `sizeof()` otherwise there is no way to know the size of the allocated pointer.

Comment: I'll admit to having no experience with them myself but I _thought_ you could do this with C11 generics, i.e. `#define MY_SPRINTF(buf, args...) (_Generic((buf), char *: sprintf((buf), ## args), default: snprintf((buf), sizeof(buf), ## args)))` or something along those lines