# How to check if an array is of constant known size?

Tags: c

In C we have pointers to arrays objects and [arrays of constant known size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array).
The NetBSD defines an [__arraycount](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?__arraycount+3) macro, which is defined as `#define __arraycount(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))`.
I wouls like to define my own `__arraycount` macro, which will not compile when given a pointer to array. To do that, i need a `__is_array_of_constant_known_size` macro.
I would like to have a macro that is a compile time constant which for arrays of constant known size will return true/nonzero and for pointers to array objects (or any other pointers) will return false/zero.
This is what i've come up with:

```
#if __GNUC__
#define __is_array_of_constant_known_size(x)  ( __builtin_constant_p((void*)x == (void*)&x)?1:0 )
#else
#define __is_array_of_constant_known_size(x)  ( (void*)&x[0] == (void*)&x )
#endif

// __arraycount may look like this:
#define __arraycount(x)  ( sizeof(char[__is_array_of_constant_known_size(x) ? 1 : -1]) ? (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])) : -1 )

// tests:
static char var1[5];
typedef char type1[__is_array_of_constant_known_size(var1)?1:-1];
static const int int1 = __is_array_of_constant_known_size(var1);
static const int sizeof1 = sizeof(char[__is_array_of_constant_known_size(var1)?1:-1]);

static char * var2;
typedef char type2[__is_array_of_constant_known_size(var2)?1:-1]; // should error
static const int int2 = __is_array_of_constant_known_size(var2);
static const int sizeof2 = sizeof(char[__is_array_of_constant_known_size(var2) 1:-1]); // should error
```

For GNUC compilers (clang6.0.0 and gcc8.1) tests are ok, ie. the lines containing `type2` and `sizeof2` fail to compile with `error: size of array is negative`.
However when GNUC is not defined, then i get:

```
<source>:8:1: warning: variably modified 'type1' at file scope
 typedef char type1[__is_array_of_constant_known_size(var1)?1:-1];
 ^~~~~~~
<source>:10:21: error: initializer element is not constant
 const int sizeof1 = sizeof(char[__is_array_of_constant_known_size(var1)?1:-1]);
                     ^~~~~~
<source>:13:14: error: variably modified 'type2' at file scope
 typedef char type2[__is_array_of_constant_known_size(var2)?1:-1];
              ^~~~~
<source>:4:47: error: initializer element is not constant
 #define __is_array_of_constant_known_size(x)  ( (void*)&x[0] == (void*)&x )
                                               ^
<source>:14:18: note: in expansion of macro '__is_array_of_constant_known_size'
 const int int2 = __is_array_of_constant_known_size(var2)?1:-1;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:15:21: error: initializer element is not constant
 const int sizeof2 = sizeof(char[__is_array_of_constant_known_size(var2)?1:-1]);
```

The line `int1 = __is_array_of_constant_known_size(var1)` compiles without error. That means, that `__is_array_of_constant_known_size(var1)` is a constant expression, because

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static
>   storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals
>   from 6.7.8 in
>   [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

But the line `sizeof1 = sizeof(char[__is_array_of_constant_known_size(var1)])` fails to compile with `error: initializer is not compile time constant`. Why is that?
Why `(void*)&var1[0] == (void*)&var1` is a constant expression, but `sizeof(char[((void*)&var1[0] == (void*)&var1)])` is not?
Is there a better way to implement compile time assertion inside the `__arraycount` macro rather then `sizeof(char[__is_array_of_constant_known_size(var1)?1:-1])`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19452971/1606345

Comment: Is your question essentially "*I would like to define my own __arraycount macro, which will not compile when given a pointer to array.*" ?

Comment: I think you might utilize the fact that `(some_int_type) p == (some_int_type)&p` for arrays, but not for pointers

Comment: @KamilCuk Cool. They use the method I just proposed.. I can be proud of myself :)