# Why is my function not able to find the size of an array?

Tags: arrays, c, size

I created a header file named **functions.h** and a source file named **test.c**.
I want to count the size of an array by doing `size=sizeof(arr)/arr[0]`.

If I do it in the `main` function, the expression works. However, it does not when I apply the header file.

For header file: **functions.h**

```
#ifndef C2A1E1_MACROS_H_INCLUDED
#define C2A1E1_MACROS_H_INCLUDED

double SizeofArray(double a[]) {
    int b = 0;
    b = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

    return b;
}
#endif // C2A1E1_MACROS_H_INCLUDED
```

For source file: **test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "functions.h"

int main(void) {
    double arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    double arrSize = 0;

    double n1 = sizeof(arr);
    printf("n1= %f\n", n1);
    double n2 = sizeof(arr[0]);
    printf("n2= %f\n", n2);
    double ArrSize = n1 / n2;
    printf("ArrSize= %f\n", ArrSize);

    //Applied Function
    arrSize = SizeofArray(arr);
    printf("Array Size= %f\n", arrSize);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the result when I run my program with Array Size = 0, but it is supposed to be 5:
[image: This]

Comment: Please don't post screen shots of text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/10349610/388520 (specifically that answer).

Comment: There should be a whole bunch of exact duplicates...

Answer (score 2):

`SizeofArray` cannot be implemented as a function because the function receives a pointer to the array, from which it cannot compute the length of the array with the posted expression.

You can define a macro for this purpose, but keep in mind that it is quite error prone as even the macro will fail when invoked with a pointer instead of an actual array:

```
#define SizeofArray(a)  (sizeof(a) / sizeof(*(a)))
```

This page has somewhat portable methods to try and detect if `a` is an actual array: [Array-size macro that rejects pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452971/array-size-macro-that-rejects-pointers)