# Please explain the following function which returns the size of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can someone explain this template code that gives me the size of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437150/can-someone-explain-this-template-code-that-gives-me-the-size-of-an-array)

```
template <typename T,unsigned S>
unsigned ArraySize(const T (&v)[S])
{
    return S;
}
```

I understand the `T` and `S`, but my question is why do we **have** to declare `v` as a reference variable? Or maybe I'm misunderstanding this whole thing.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I didn't really know what keywords to use for searching my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function accepts an array *by reference*, and because of this, type of element `T` and size `S` is deduced by the compiler. So it returns `S` which is nothing but the size of the array. In the absence of *reference*, it would decay into a pointer type. So there is no difference between these:

```
void f(int v[100]);  //declaration of f
void f(int v[200]);  //redeclaration of f
void f(int v[]);     //redeclaration of f
void f(int *v);      //redeclaration of f
```

All are exactly same. You can pass array of any size to all of these functions.

---

Coming back to `ArraySize`, the returned value of this function cannot be used as constant expression:

```
int a[10];
SomeClassTemplate<ArraySize(a)> obj; //error
```

See error  : http://ideone.com/4mdJE

So a better implementation would be this:

```
template <typename T,unsigned S>
char (&ArraySizeHelper(const T (&v)[S]))[S];  //no need to define it!
#define ArraySize(a) sizeof(ArraySizeHelper(a))
```

Now this is perfectly fine:

```
int a[10];
SomeClassTemplate<ArraySize(a)> obj; //ok
```

See ok : http://ideone.com/Zt3UY

Comment: That's pretty awesome. And I thought I knew C++. Any suggestions for other quick reads to learn some useful tricks like these?

Comment: @quuxbazer: If you want to learn more and better C++ here at stackoverflow itself, then follow these guys : [@Alf P. Steinbach](http://stackoverflow.com/users/464581/alf-p-steinbach), [Johannes Schaub - litb](http://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb), [MSalters](http://stackoverflow.com/users/15416/msalters), [David Rodríguez - dribeas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/36565/david-rodriguez-dribeas), [James Kanze](http://stackoverflow.com/users/649665/james-kanze), [Charles Bailey](http://stackoverflow.com/users/19563/charles-bailey)

Comment: @quuxbazer: And how can I forget them : [@James McNellis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/151292/james-mcnellis), [AndreyT](http://stackoverflow.com/users/187690/andreyt). Go to their profile, read the posts they've posted, including the questions they ever asked.

Comment: @quuxbazer: Since you're new at Stackoverflow, I would also like to redirect you to this page : [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 2):

If v wasn't a reference, then you would have this:

```
template <typename T,unsigned S>
unsigned ArraySize(const T v[S])
{
    return S;
}
```

But the use of [] in this context is just another way of writing

```
template <typename T,unsigned S>
unsigned ArraySize(const T *v)
{
    return S;
}
```

which would give you no size information.