# How to get the real and total length of char * (char array)?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, char

For a `char []`, I can easily get its length by:

```
char a[] = "aaaaa";
int length = sizeof(a)/sizeof(char); // length=6
```

However, I cannot do like this to get the length of a `char *` by:

```
char *a = new char[10];
int length = sizeof(a)/sizeof(char);
```

because, I know, `a` here is a pointer, such that `length` here will be always be `4` (or something other in different systems).

My question is that how can I get the length of a `char *` afterwards? *I know someone may challenge me that you already know its `10` because you just created it. I want to know this because this step of getting its length may come long long way from its creation and I don't want to come long long way back to check this number. Moreover, I also want to know its real length.*

To be more specific

- how can I get its real `length=5`?
- how can I get its total `length=10`?

for the following example:

```
char *a = new char[10]; 
strcpy(a, "hello");
```

Comment: `strlen`? (....)

Comment: You cannot get the length of the array a pointer it points to. You need to keep track of it by other means.

Comment: @KillianDS - yes, of course. I may have misunderstood the question, that's why I wrote a comment.

Comment: @KirilKirov that will not give the length of the array. Well, it will, but only in special circumstances.

Comment: @juanchopanza - true, but "My question is that how can I get the length of a char * afterwards" sounds a bit misleading - it's not clear if the expected result is the length of the _array_ or of the _string_, pointed by the pointer.

Comment: This has been answered before, a pointer doesn't hold information about the size of the block of data it points to (if it points to an array), just its starting location in memory.

Comment: @KirilKirov Agreed, the "length of a char*" is not very clear.

Comment: You may use `std::vector<char>`, so you have the size, and memory management is done for you

Comment: Using vectors won't work in C though, hurts portability :p, but   a good idea nonetheless!

Comment: @Siidheesh - I disagree. First, the question is about C++, second - you still can take `char*` from a `vector`. Also, if you want really "portability" between C and C++, this means - use only C (and even then, it's not 100% "portable" in this sense)

Comment: If there was a way around this problem, I imagine that passing the length of arrays around would be obsolete.

Comment: Just throw in a memset for zeroing out the memory locations, use strlen and bob's yer uncle xD

Comment: @herohuyongtao `a = "hello"` is wrong in so many ways.. But at least the edit makes the question a bit more clear.

Comment: Could you please decide which language you're asking about? If it's C, then you can't use `new`; if it's C++, then you should use higher-level abstractions like `vector` to solve this problem.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I removed the C tag b/c as it is stated it is not a C question, I wish I noticed that earlier.

Comment: The gist is to explicitly declare array structures as arrays unless otherwise required, because arrays can collapse easily into pointers but pointers cannot become arrays.

Comment: You may be interested in `std::array<char, 10>` too.

Comment: Since the C tag has been added a removed several times I have flagged the question and we will let a mod determine this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about C-Strings which any C or C++ programming book will tell you about.

Comment: Found an interesting tidbit, read more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437150/can-someone-explain-this-template-code-that-gives-me-the-size-of-an-array.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can't. Not with 100% accuracy, anyway. The pointer *has no length/size but its own*. All it does is point to a particular place in memory that holds a char. If that char is part of a string, then you can use `strlen` to determine what chars follow the one currently being pointed to, but that doesn't mean the *array* in your case is that big.
Basically:

A ***pointer*** is not an ***array***, so it doesn't *need* to know what the size of the array is. A pointer can point to a single value, so a pointer can exist without there even being an array. It doesn't even care where the memory it points to is situated (Read only, heap or stack... doesn't matter). A pointer doesn't have a length other than itself. A pointer just is...
Consider this:

```
char beep = '\a';
void alert_user(const char *msg, char *signal); //for some reason
alert_user("Hear my super-awsome noise!", &beep); //passing pointer to single char!

void alert_user(const char *msg, char *signal)
{
    printf("%s%c\n", msg, *signal);
}
```

A pointer can be a single char, as well as the beginning, end or middle of an array...
Think of chars as structs. You sometimes allocate a single struct on the heap. That, too, creates a pointer without an array.

Using only a pointer, to determine how big an array it is pointing to is impossible. The closest you can get to it is using `calloc` and counting the number of consecutive \0 chars you can find through the pointer. Of course, that doesn't work once you've assigned/reassigned stuff to that array's keys and it also fails if the memory just *outside* of the array happens to hold `\0`, too. So using this method is unreliable, dangerous and just generally silly. Don't. Do. It.

*Another analogy:*
Think of a pointer as a road sign, it points to *Town X*. The sign doesn't know what that town looks like, and it doesn't know or care (or can care) who lives there. It's job is to tell you where to find *Town X*. It can only tell you how far that town is, but not how big it is. That information is deemed irrelevant for road-signs. That's something that you can only find out by looking at the town itself, not at the road-signs that are pointing you in its direction

So, using a pointer the only thing you can do is:

```
char a_str[] = "hello";//{h,e,l,l,o,\0}
char *arr_ptr = &a_str[0];
printf("Get length of string -> %d\n", strlen(arr_ptr));
```

But this, of course, only works if the array/string is \0-terminated.

As an aside:

```
int length = sizeof(a)/sizeof(char);//sizeof char is guaranteed 1, so sizeof(a) is enough
```

is actually assigning `size_t` (the return type of `sizeof`) to an `int`, best write:

```
size_t length = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);//best use ptr's type -> good habit
```

Since `size_t` is an unsigned type, if `sizeof` returns bigger values, the value of `length` might be something you didn't expect...

Comment: @herohuyongtao: using a pointer, you can't get the _max-length_. in your snippet `new char[10]` allocates 10 chars, and assigns the pointer to `a`. You can use `strlen(a)` _after_ `strcpy`, and it'll return 5, but getting the 10 is not possible, not unless you do something like `char *a = calloc(10, sizeof *a);`, then `for(i=0;a[i] == '\0';++i);` after that, `i-1` _could_ give you the total length of the memory allocated, if the memory right next to the allocated block doesn't _accidentally_ hold `\0`, too, so this is dangerous and bad. But you're using C++: use `std::string` or `std::vector`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, isn't a[0]==0[a]==*a? Why would using sizeof (*a) be a better habit than using sizeof (a[0])? Unless you meant that it's better than using sizeof(a) by itself...

Comment: @Siidheesh: Strictly speaking `a[0] == 0[a] == *(a+0)`, but the main reason for using `sizeof *a` is when using other types than char, or usign pointers to pointers in custom allocators. consider `void my_alloc(void **ptr, size_t size) { (*ptr) = malloc(size*sizeof(*(*ptr)));}` this will work when allocating structs, ints, chars... any type, whereas `sizeof(type)` requires your knowing the type.

Comment: @APerson: I did mean to say that using `sizeof *a` is better than using `sizeof <type>`, and a lot better than `sizeof a` (which is not always what you want). Personally, I also happen to prefer `*a` over `a[0]`, simply because it makes it very clearl (IMHO) that a pointer is being dereferenced. When reviewing code, or hunting down the cause of a segfault, these lines that are my first port of call. When I see `a[0]`, I might be assume (wrongly) that `a` is a local array variable, and not a NULL pointer

Answer (score 24):

If the `char *` is 0-terminated, you can use `strlen`

Otherwise, there is no way to determine that information

Comment: `strlen` will not reliably give the length of the array.

Comment: @Olotiar Unless you're working with a specific compiler and locate where the data regarding allocated memory is stored (after all, in order for memory allocation to work properly, the amount of memory that was allocated for that specific location needs to be stored somewhere so it won't be overlapped by another allocation and so that `free` will work properly).

Comment: `strlen` *does not* count the `'\0'`.

Comment: @JAB This is a good remark, though I don't know of any standard way to access that information.

Comment: @JAB That would still only work if it's dynamically allocated.

Comment: For my example (updated), how to get 10 as `strlen` can only get me 5?

Comment: You can't. Use a sentinel (special delimiter character), an `int` to remember the length, a custom made struct, or a higher level structure like `std::vector` in c++

Comment: @MarounMaroun Then just add +1 for the `\0`. One can also do the counting on his own by simply saving a copy of the pointer and increasing it gradually until the `\0` is reached. Of course one needs to make sure that the string is actually `\0`-terminated. Another thing that needs to be made clear here is that one has to use `malloc` or some other method for getting a continuous chunk of memory. Otherwise the incrementation of the pointer may land in a block that stores information from something else leading either to obtaining garbage data or a crash.

Answer (score 7):

There are only two ways:

- If the memory pointer to by your `char *` represents a C string (that is, it contains characters that have a 0-byte to mark its end), you can use `strlen(a)`.
- Otherwise, you need to store the length somewhere. Actually, the pointer only points to *one* `char`. But we can treat it as if it points to the first element of an array. Since the "length" of that array isn't known you need to store that information somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

- In C++:

Just use `std::vector<char>` which keep the (dynamic) size for you. (Bonus, memory management for free).

Or `std::array<char, 10>` which keep the (static) size.

- In pure C:

Create a structure to keep the info, something like:

```
typedef struct {
    char* ptr;
    int size;
} my_array;

my_array malloc_array(int size)
{
    my_array res;
    res.ptr = (char*) malloc(size);
    res.size = size;
    return res;
}

void free_array(my_array array)
{
    free(array.ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

So the thing with the **sizeof** operator is that it returns you the amount of storage needed, in bytes, to store the operand.

The amount of storage needed to store a char is always 1 byte. So the `sizeof(char)` will always return 1.

```
char a[] = "aaaaa";

int len1 = sizeof(a)/sizeof(char); // length = 6
int len2 = sizeof(a);              // length = 6;
```

This is the same for both `len1` and `len2` because this division of 1 does not influence the equation.

The reason why both `len1` and `len2` carry the value 6 has to do with the string termination char `'\0'`. Which is also a char which adds another char to the length. Therefore your length is going to be 6 instead of the 5 you were expecting.

```
char *a = new char[10];
int length = sizeof(a)/sizeof(char);
```

You already mentioned that the length turns out to be 4 here, which is correct. Again, the **sizeof** operator returns the storage amount for the operand and in your case it is a pointer `a`. A pointer requires 4 bytes of storage and therefore the length is 4 in this case. Since you probably compile it to a 32-bit binary. If you'd created a 64-bit binary the outcome would be 8.

This explanation might be here already be here. Just want to share my two cents.

Answer (score 3):

Given just the pointer, you can't. You'll have to keep hold of the length you passed to `new[]` or, better, use `std::vector` to both keep track of the length, and release the memory when you've finished with it.

<sub>Note: this answer only addresses C++, not C.</sub>

Comment: Assuming he's only using C++. If the code needs to work as a C program as well, then `std::vector` will unfortunately not be much help.

Comment: @JAB: Oh yes, I just noticed the question is asking about two languages at once. I wish people would stop doing that.

Comment: If he's using `new`, he can't be using C.

Comment: @JohnDibling True, but the question was tagged with both `C++` and `C` (though it is not anymore).

Answer (score 3):

> char *a = new char[10];
>
> My question is that how can I get the length of a char *

It is very simply.:) It is enough to add only one statement

```
size_t N = 10;
char *a = new char[N];
```

Now you can get the size of the allocated array

```
std::cout << "The size is " << N << std::endl;
```

Many mentioned here C standard function std::strlen. But it does not return the actual size of a character array. It returns only the size of stored string literal.

The difference is the following. if to take your code snippet as an example

```
char a[] = "aaaaa";
int length = sizeof(a)/sizeof(char); // length=6
```

then std::strlen( a ) will return 5 instead of 6 as in your code.

So the conclusion is simple: if you need to dynamically allocate a character array consider usage of class `std::string`. It has methof size and its synonym length that allows to get the size of the array at any time.

For example

```
std::string s( "aaaaa" );

std::cout << s.length() << std::endl;
```

or

```
std::string s;
s.resize( 10 );

std::cout << s.length() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own `new` and `delete` functions, as well as an additional `get-size` function:

```
#define CEIL_DIV(x,y) (((x)-1)/(y)+1)

void* my_new(int size)
{
    if (size > 0)
    {
        int* ptr = new int[1+CEIL_DIV(size,sizeof(int))];
        if (ptr)
        {
            ptr[0] = size;
            return ptr+1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void my_delete(void* mem)
{
    int* ptr = (int*)mem-1;
    delete ptr;
}

int my_size(void* mem)
{
    int* ptr = (int*)mem-1;
    return ptr[0];
}
```

Alternatively, you can override the `new` and `delete` operators in a similar manner.

Comment: +1 for creativity, although I wouldn't recommend doing that in a real application. You'd also have to implement copy and resize. When using C++, there are better ways to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I know this is an ancient thread.
According to my experiments, an assignment like:

```
char* str = "blah";
```

*does* indeed append a null character. This code:

```
char* str = "blah";
cout << str;
cout << strlen(str);
```

Outputs:

blah

4

It still works if I change the number of characters assigned. Since the assignment does seem to add a \0 at the end, I don't understand the above admonitions ("strlen only works if there's a nul char" etc.) Am I missing something?

Comment: String **literals** are null terminated automatically.  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: That said, in my opinion, it's a truly terrible practice to write code passing around a char * with the assumption that it is definitely null terminated.  If you want a "string", I think 99% of the time one is better off just using an std::string (or string type from some other library).  You can pass them around just as well by reference, or pointer, to avoid needless copies (if that's a concern).  The disadvantage of using some tiny amount of extra memory or processing with a wrapped object is generally negligible compared to the risk, or the pita, of using char * primitives.

Answer (score 1):

This may sound Evil™ and I haven't tested it, but how about initializing all values in an array at allocation to `'\0'` and then using `strlen()` ? This would give you your so-called *real value* since it would stop counting at the first `'\0'` it encounters.

Well, now that I think about it though, please don't Ever™ do this. Unless, you want to land in a pile of dirty memory.

Also, for the allocated memory or the *total memory* you may use the following functions if your environment provides them:

- [msize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2s077bc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [malloc_usable_size()](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/package/rtems/doc/html/libc/libc.info.malloc.html)

Comment: If you set all of the values of a char * array to `'\0'`, then `strlen()` will return 0.

Comment: @sharth, that is indeed the _real value_ he wants, since what you mentioned is only the case when the memory hasn't been used yet. Assuming he changes the elements by equalising them to _real values_ he won't get 0 from a call to strlen() anymore.

Comment: This can lead to some problems when the char array contains binary informations (image pointer for instance) : the array can contains '\0' bytes in the data and in this case, the data length is greater than strlen(data).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a back-tracker character, ex, you could append any special character say "%" to the end of your string and then check the occurrence of that character.
But this is a very risky way as that character can be in other places also in the char*

```
char* stringVar = new char[4] ; 
stringVar[0] = 'H' ; 
stringVar[1] = 'E' ; 
stringVar[2] = '$' ; // back-tracker character.
int i = 0 ;
while(1)
{
   if (stringVar[i] == '$')
     break ; 
   i++ ; 
}
//  i is the length of the string.
// you need to make sure, that there is no other $ in the char*
```

Otherwise define a custom structure to keep track of length and allocate memory.

Comment: Ugh, that smells awfully! Null-terminate the string instead. It's a bad idea to use a character that might turn up in actual text (like, "You owe me $1 for that terrible idea" ;-)

Comment: @ps06756: still crashes `stringVar = new char[10]`, and doesn't answer the OP question.

Answer (score 0):

when new allocates an array, depending on the compiler (i use gnu c++), the word in front of the array contains information about the number of bytes allocated.

The test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main ()
{
    int arraySz;
    char *a;
    unsigned int *q;

    for (arraySz = 5; arraySz <= 64; arraySz++) {

        printf ("%02d - ", arraySz);

        a = new char[arraySz];
        unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *) a;

        q = (unsigned int *) (a - 4);
        printf ("%02d\n", (*q));

        delete[] (a);

    }
}
```

on my machine dumps out:

```
05 - 19
06 - 19
07 - 19
08 - 19
09 - 19
10 - 19
11 - 19
12 - 19
13 - 27
14 - 27
15 - 27
16 - 27
17 - 27
18 - 27
19 - 27
20 - 27
21 - 35
22 - 35
23 - 35
24 - 35
25 - 35
26 - 35
27 - 35
28 - 35
29 - 43
30 - 43
31 - 43
32 - 43
33 - 43
34 - 43
35 - 43
36 - 43
37 - 51
38 - 51
39 - 51
40 - 51
41 - 51
42 - 51
43 - 51
44 - 51
45 - 59
46 - 59
47 - 59
48 - 59
49 - 59
50 - 59
51 - 59
52 - 59
53 - 67
54 - 67
55 - 67
56 - 67
57 - 67
58 - 67
59 - 67
60 - 67
61 - 75
62 - 75
63 - 75
64 - 75
```

I would not recommend this solution (vector is better), but if you are really desperate, you could find a relationship and be able to conclude the number of bytes allocated from the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Legit question. I personally think people confuse pointers with arrays **as a result of character pointers (char*)**, which serve almost the same purpose as **character arrays (char __[X])**. This means that pointers and arrays are not the same, so pointers of course don't contain a specific size, only an address if I could say so. But nonetheless you can try something similar to strlen.

```
int ssize(const char* s)
{
    for (int i = 0; ; i++)
        if (s[i] == 0)
            return i;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find the length of a char* string like this:

```
char* mystring = "Hello World";
int length = sprintf(mystring, "%s", mystring);
```

sprintf() prints mystring onto itself, and returns the number of characters printed.

Comment: So it's exactly equivalent to `strlen`, and only works if the last character in the array is a NUL, and there are no NULs before that.

Answer (score -2):

You could try this:

```
int lengthChar(const char* chararray) {
   int n = 0;
   while(chararray[n] != '\0')
     n ++;
   return n;  
}
```

Comment: That's just (a poor implementation of) `strlen()`, with all its limitations ().

Answer (score -4):

Strlen command is working for me . You can try following code.

// char *s

```
unsigned int  strLength=strlen(s);
```

Comment: Depends on `s`.. Is it a C String?

Comment: Only if you put a terminated string in the array; and then you'll get the length of the string, not the array.

Comment: I guess the you didn't want to paste the first three lines.

Comment: Put your array like this , and try please...

char a[]="aaaaa";
WriteString (100, 225, &a);

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. No `return` statement, no `}`, and wrapping a call to `strlen` in a function with unused arguments, unused variables and misleading name is absolutely horrible. Also, you're trying to pass a `char **` as argument in your comment.

Comment: You all right. I give sample code for idea.But This is only a code part.

Comment: If you want you can use this code...
int WriteString(char *s){
  return strlen(s);

}

Comment: Why do you insist on wrapping `strlen` in a function called `WriteString`? Your function does not write a string, it returns the length of a string.

Comment: Because it is only a code part from my projects. Actually it is a tft display driver code for fujitsu chip.

Comment: Please read the previous answers and the question to get a firm idea of the question being asked here. Thank you.