# Understanding _countof macro

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename _CountofType, size_t _SizeOfArray>
char( *__countof_helper1( _CountofType(&_Array)[_SizeOfArray]))[_SizeOfArray];

#define _myCountOf(_Array) (sizeof(*__countof_helper1(_Array)) + 0)
```

I'm trying to understand _countof Macro, but unable to understand how its able to calculate the size of array. Please someone explain bit by bit the above code

Comment: Above duplicate has specifics for this macro, and also links to more general explanations.

Comment: Also read: [what are the rules about using an underscore in an identifier/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797)

Answer (score 5):

It's an overly complicated declaration. In modern C++, you can do just this:

```
template<typename T, size_t SizeOfArray>
constexpr size_t countof(T (&array)[SizeOfArray]) { return SizeOfArray; }
```

The crux of the solution is `T (&array)[SizeOfArray]`: it's the syntax you need to pass a reference to an array. `T` and `SizeOfArray` are inferred by the compiler, so it'll have valid values for any array you throw at it.

In your helper case, the programmer probably didn't have access to `constexpr` but still wanted to make sure that the expression was evaluated at compile-time rather than at runtime. It's confusing because the C++ function declaration syntax is confusing: it declares a function that accepts an array of any type and length and returns an array of characters of the same length. It then uses `sizeof` to find the length of the character array and returns that.

Comment: also covered here pretty well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437150/can-someone-explain-this-template-code-that-gives-me-the-size-of-an-array