# Why does this template for an array's size not work?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, size, c++14

As some practice for using templates, I tried to write a function template to find the size of an array:

```
template <typename T>
size_t arraySize(T array[]) {
    return (sizeof(array)/sizeof(T));
}
```

I then tried to test the template with a few arrays of different data types alongside regular sizeof(array)/sizeof(datatype) computations as follows:

```
int main(){

int arr1[20];
char arr2[20];
double arr3[20];

cout << arraySize(arr1) << ' ' << arraySize(arr2) << ' ' << arraySize(arr3) << endl;
cout << sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(int) << ' ' << sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(char) << ' ' << sizeof(arr3)/sizeof(double);

}
```

The output is

```
2 8 1
20 20 20
```

Why does this template not work as expected?

Note: I am aware of the existence of other questions relating to array size with templates on Stack Overflow [(such as this one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437150/can-someone-explain-this-template-code-that-gives-me-the-size-of-an-array), but I'm mainly confused as to why this specific code doesn't work.

Comment: @Koopa184 I would like to keep the `c++1y` tag because there is a pending Standard proposal to add this function to the Standard Library. This makes it easier for future readers.

Comment: @TemplateRex Sorry, I misunderstood! That's fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that `T array[]` is really `T* array`. To get the actual size you need to pass an array by reference, i.e, parameter `T (&array)[N]`, with `N` being an integer template parameter.

Comment: `T (array&)[N]` should be `T (&array)[N]` or even `const T (&array)[N]` in this case.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer has prompted me to further explore pointer decay and references.

Comment: @Koopa184 the parameter list to a function is a [special case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677415/why-do-c-and-c-compilers-allow-array-lengths-in-function-signatures-when-they/22677793). It's not a decay, it's just a strange syntax.

Comment: @Constructor The `const` is not necessary in this case -- it will be inferred for constant arrays by template argument deduction, anyway.

Comment: @FredOverflow It is a simple tamper protection for non-constant arrays. Of course, `arraySize` function is too short and simple to make such error in it, but it is not the reason to violate the general rule: function parameters which shouldn't be changed inside the function body should be marked as `const`.

Comment: I find `template<class T>using type=T;` makes these declarations easier: `size_t arraySize(type<T[N]>&)` reads easier to me than `T(&)[N]`.

Answer (score 7):

[**Arrays decay to pointers**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/819272) when you don't pass a reference to a sized array:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
size_t arraySize(T const (& array)[N]) {
    return N; // equivalent to: (sizeof(array)/sizeof(T));
}

using namespace std;

int main(){

int arr1[20];
char arr2[20];
double arr3[20];

cout << arraySize(arr1) << ' ' << arraySize(arr2) << ' ' << arraySize(arr3) << endl;
cout << sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(int) << ' ' << sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(char) << ' ' << sizeof(arr3)/sizeof(double);

}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fc4c43ccbc6fd64) that prints 6 times 20.

**UPDATE**: there is a current proposal [**N4017**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4017.htm) for the upcoming C++1y Standard that proposes a non-member `size()` function in the Standard Library. For all Standard Containers this will delegate to the `size()` member functions, but for raw arrays the proposed implementation is almost equivalent (with the addition of `constexpr` and `noexcept`)  to what I've written above:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t size(const T (&array)[N]) noexcept
{
    return N;
}
```

Comment: `const T (&array)[N]` is more appropriate notation in this case.

Comment: Might as well `return N;`.

Comment: @chris sure, I just wanted to show that his original attempt can be made to work, updating.

Comment: Just a note to say that N4280, an updated paper of N4017, has been accepted into the C++17 Working Draft.