# How does boost serialization library detect array?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

In the [tutorial for the boost serialization library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#arrays)  it says that "The serialization library detects when the object being serialized is an array" and therefore code like `bus_stop * stops[10]; ar & stops;` is equivalent to using a for loop `for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { ar & stops[i]; }`.

How can the library determine at runtime to how many elements the pointer `stops` points to? Or even that it actually is an array and not a pointer to a single object? I wasn't able to find any hint in the source code yet.

Thanks!

Comment: See e.g. [this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437150/can-someone-explain-this-template-code-that-gives-me-the-size-of-an-array).

Comment: Variables in C++ have a statically known *type*, and you can write generic code that acts differently for different types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that `stops` is not a pointer, it's an array (of 10 pointers to `bus_stop`, but that's irrelevant).

Arrays are *not* pointers. There is an implicit conversion from *array* to *pointer to first element of the array* which happens when you pass e.g. an array of `char` to a function expecting a `char *` parameter. But that conversion only happens when required.

If a function takes an array *by reference,* the conversion (also known as array-to-pointer decay) will of course not happen, so that the argument can bind to the parameter. In other words, all it takes is a suitable function template:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
void operator & (some_type lhs, T (&array)[N]);
```

This will only accept arrays as the right-hand side argument.

Notice that if, in your original code, you did this instead:

```
bus_stop * stops[10];
bus_stop ** p_stops = stops; // decay happens here

ar & p_stops;
```

then the last line would *not* invoke the array overload. The type of `stops` is an array. The type of `p_stops` is a pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation. But what would the operator template for the pointer `p_stops` look like? If it would be a general implementation like `template<typename T> void operator&(T* p)` then the operator `&` is ambigous for the array.

Comment: @cwde Yes, it would look like that, and no, it's not ambiguous. The array-based template matches perfectly. The pointer-based template would require an array-to-pointer conversion. Therefore, the array-based template is a strictly better match, and so is chosen.

Comment: I just tried it in a simple code example with an array of 6 ints. The compiler (VS10) says the operator is ambiguous for it could be `operator &<int>(T *)` or `operator &<int,6>(T (&)[6])`.

Comment: @cwde Wow, you got me. I didn't expect that, but Clang reports the same ambiguity. I've never used Boost serialisation. Does it provide an overload for pointers? Perhaps that's just implemented as `void*`, not a template? That would disambiguate it.

Comment: Yes with `void*` it is disambiguated, but that leads me to another question: how will the serialization process go on from there as one cannot dereference a `void*` pointer? Of course the answer must be somewhere in the source code of boost, but I can't figure out where to find it. Maybe someone else can help out here?

Comment: @cwde Does it actually need an overload for pointers at all? You can't meaningfully serialise a pointer anyway. At best, you could store the address it points to - but you can do that just fine with a `void*`.

Comment: Hm at least it must have an overload ( see [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#pointers) ). It will of course not store the address but the content it points to and therefore will call the operator for the dereferenced object. But this is not possible with a `void*`... Anyways I guess I should spend more time on going through the code so we don't get a lengthy comment discussion here :)