# Specialization of a template class (array as input for the constructor)?

Tags: c++, arrays

Let's say that I have a template class:

```
template <typename T>
class TC
{
...
};
```

and two normal classes:

```
class A
{
...
};

class B : public A
{
...
}
```

and I can explicitly instantiate

```
TC<std::string> a(someString);
TC<int> a(5);
TC<A> a(someTestClassA);
TC<B> a(someTestClassB);
```

and I want to specialize the template class so that it can accept an dynamic array as constructor input:

```
TC<int[]> a(new int[5]);
TC<int[]> b(a);
TC<B[]> c(new B[5]);
```

How do I "read" the size of the array inside my constructor?

The specialization would be (I think) as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class TC<T []>
{
    public:
    TC() : ptr(new T[n]) { }

    T * ptr;
};
```

How to find out the number n?

EDIT:

The number n is explicitly stated in the main function (so, main knows the number at compile time but how do I tell the TC[] constructor what n is?).
Example:

```
TC<int[]> a(new int[5]); // in the TC[] class constructor, n should be 5
```

I think that I am looking for an analogon of the following (but for classes i.e. constructors):

```
template <typename T, size_t N> 
void f( T (&a)[N])
{
    for(size_t i=0; i != N; ++i) a[i]=0;
}
```

Comment: You can't read length/size of passed array. Not in templates, and not in any other construct. Pass it in as another variable to the function (constructor in this case)

Comment: in this line: TC<int[]> a(new int[5]);  , n is equal to 5 and is known at compile time, i.e. I explicitly state this number in the source code

Comment: The type of `new int[5]` is `int*`.  There is no way to get the dimension 5 back from that expression.

Comment: @AltairAC _"The number n is explicitly stated in the main function"_ You'd still need a specialization for `int[5]` (and so essentially for every possible size), it's actually not the same as `int[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"How to find out the number n?"*

You cannot.

Use [`std::array<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead (or [`std::vector<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if you don't know the actual size at compile time), they were designed to solve these kind of problems.

---

Related Q&A: [**Can someone explain this template code that gives me the size of an array?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437150/can-someone-explain-this-template-code-that-gives-me-the-size-of-an-array)

You'd still may not want to implement this yourself, that could get hard to be used in specializations.

Answer (score 3):

You could partially specialize on a raw-array of known size:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class TC<T[N]>
{
public:
    TC() : ptr(new T[N]) { }
private:
    T* ptr;
};

TC<int[4]> dynamic_array_of_4_ints;
```

Though this is sort of halfway between `std::array<T, N> a` and `std::vector<T> v(N)`, and likely worse than both.