# debug template for array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, debugging

I want to create debug template for array for printing array.
This is my template

```
#define debug(x) cerr << #x <<" = "; print(x); cerr << endl;

void print(ll t) {cerr << t;}
void print(int t) {cerr << t;}
void print(float t) {cerr << t;}
void print(string t) {cerr << t;}
void print(char t) {cerr << t;}

template <class T> void print(vector <T> v) {cerr << "[ "; for (T i : v) {print(i); cerr << " ";} cerr << "]";}
```

```
template <class T> void print(T arr[]) {cerr << "[ "; for (T i : arr) {print(i); cerr << " ";} cerr << "]";}
```

But its giving some errors for array but vector works fine,

```
 template <class T> void print(T arr[]) {cerr << "[ "; for (T i : arr) {print(i); cerr << " ";} cerr << "]";}
                                                       ^~~
A.cpp:16:55: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits\stdc++.h:95:0,
                 from A.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\valarray:1206:5: note:   'std::begin'
     begin(const valarray<_Tp>& __va)
     ^~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\valarray:1206:5: note:   'std::begin'
A.cpp:16:55: error: 'end' was not declared in this scope
 template <class T> void print(T arr[]) {cerr << "[ "; for (T i : arr) {print(i); cerr << " ";} cerr << "]";}
                                                       ^~~
A.cpp:16:55: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits\stdc++.h:95:0,
                 from A.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\valarray:1226:5: note:   'std::end'
     end(const valarray<_Tp>& __va)
     ^~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\valarray:1226:5: note:   'std::end'
```

So how to create a debug for array ?

Comment: You might want to check your const correctness of your code, printing should not be able to modify data. Also use const T& instead of T as argument types (to avoid unnecessary copies).

Comment: the syntax of c and c++ are almost same so I thought that people who know c can also be able to understand this query and provide a solution if possible @Yunnosch

Comment: i think there is quite a good enough explanation for this question and all the code giving is necessary to explain question @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A range-based for loop (`for(T i : v)` internally uses [std::begin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [std::end](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) to determine the range it hast to iterate over. These methods work for arrays whose size is fixed at compile time, e.g. `int arr[10];`, for any standard container, like `std::vector`, `std::list`, or any class that has a `.begin()` and `.end()`-method that return iterators, I think.

However, it does *not* work for pointers.

In fact `print(T arr[])` equals `print(T *arr)`. You can't determine the length of an array, when you only got a pointer. You can't even determine wether or not this pointer is pointing to an array. So you can't use range-based for loops with pointers.

> So how to create a debug for array ?

If you want to use dynamically allocated arrays you have to pass the arrays size along

```
template <class T> void print(T v[], size_t size)
```

and use a normal for loop

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) { ... }
```

Another possibility is to make a template for array-size, as in this question: [Can someone explain this template code that gives me the size of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437150/can-someone-explain-this-template-code-that-gives-me-the-size-of-an-array)